# Duda en odoo para hacer unique un campo sin usar sentencia sql

Tags: python, odoo, openerp

El tema es que hace tiempo hice un exámen de **odoo**, en el me pedían que un campo de una tabla fuese único

se que con sql seria algo así

```
_sql_constraints = [('def_identification_unique', 'unique(blablabla)', 
'blablabla must be unique!')]
```

Querria saber como hacer que el campo fuese único pero usando una función de python.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un campo único se añade la constraint en la definición del modelo con Python, cuando vamos a crear la tabla o cuando creamos el campo (no podríamos añadirla a un campo con datos previos.

```
_sql_constraints = [
        ('nombre_constraint', 'unique(nombre_campo)', "Mensaje a mostra en caso de violación"),
    ]
```

Hay un hilo abierto sobre el tema en: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513326](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513326/what-is-the-correct-format-to-use-unique-in-sql-constraints-in-openerp)